# Is there way to get return value from reducer action? (in React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm making an app using React-Native.

I have a data array in redux state.
I would say it's User's array.

I want to pick one user and get his data directly from reducer state.

But I can't get a return value from reducer action. 
And accessing a store and use getState() doesn't seem a good way. Firstly, it's too hard to access 'store' instance located in root component.

What options do I have?

- Note : I already know I can add another state like 'pickedUser' and set it by action. But I want to know if there is another way to get state directly.

I'm looking for something like calling an action and get the return value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to pick one user and get his data directly from reducer state.

There is nothing like a reducer state. A reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state.

It should never be called by yourself but by redux to update the state. You can listen for state changes by connecting e.g. your react components to the store with the `connect()` function from the [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) package. If a part of the state that your components is listening to updates it will trigger a re-render of that connected component by passing the updated state as props. This is the way to react to state changes.

> I'm looking for something like calling an action and get the return value.

Redux actions do not return anything. They just trigger changes of the global state which you can then listen to. If you need to e.g. fetch data (to update the state with) inside an action you need some kind of async action which e.g. [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) provides.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. It helped me a lot to understand how it works.

Comment: I solved what I want by using redux's store.getState(). To do that, I assign 'store' object to a static variable of static class. and access it. I had a skeptical mind to use this approach, but it's working.

Comment: By the way, what you said to me is definitely the right answer. But do you think there is no matters that I solved it by accessing redux's store directly?

Comment: Generally it's fine to to that. But in combination with react it's generally a better idea to make full use of `react-redux` bindings. Wrap all your components into a `<Provider>` component that gets passed the store as a prop. You can then connect every component down the tree that needs data from the store with the `connect()` function. See [Usage with react](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#usage-with-react) from the redux docs for a detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

New version you can use useSelector() and useDispatch() with redux...still you need to use Redux-thunk for all your async calls

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function to the action that the action calls when it's complete and passes the needed value to the function. For example, I am using this within a onClick callback to get an entity id that I need to navigate to after creating it.